# Mounted partition is read-only?

Tags: permissions, partition

I have a partition mounted from /dev/sda3 to /foo.  It appears that it is not writable.  I cannot change this with "chmod /foo 777", so how I can do this?

Comment: Can you post the result from `mount`?

Comment: There was no result.  "sudo mount /dev/sda3 /foo" just went to the next line.  No output.

Comment: Was the partition mounted read-write, then suddenly changed to read-only? In that case see mailq's comment to my answer.

Comment: @coffee - he/she was referring to running `mount` by itself. No parameters.

Comment: Pasting the line I'm assuming you want from "mount": "/dev/sda3 on /foo type ext3 (rw)"

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `mount -o remount,rw /foo`.

Edit: by your comment I see this hasn't got anything to do with the partition being mounted read-only. Just run the chmod with sudo, in case you weren't doing that already. Failing that try adding 'defaults' to the mount options first. Remember to edit `/etc/fstab` if you want to make the changes permanent.

Comment: This is **critical**. A suddenly readonly mount point indicates some failures of the hard drive or the filesystem. First watch the logfiles for indication and if they are clean then issue the command.

Comment: Are you sure this is sudden? I interpreted the question as a partitition having been mounted read-only as a mistake. Your comment is spot-on for the situation you describe and a good warning, but I'm not sure this is the kind of situation the OP is in.

Comment: I ran this.  It provided no output, and still cannot be written to.  I mounted with "mount /dev/sda3 /foo".  I cd into /foo and try "touch foo.txt", get Permission denied.  @Eduoardo Ivanec is right.  This is not sudden.  I think it is a mistake

Comment: @coffee - please do post the output of `mount`. You're running all commands (including the `touch`) as root, right?

Comment: I've added the line I think you are interested in from 'mount'.  It seems I can perform 'touch' if I use sudo, but how can I change the permissions so everybody can write there?